# Fluent-ASsertions ShouldRaisePropertyChangeFor does not work for async Tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, async-await, fluent-assertions

I have a simple class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I invoke the property change on another thread, and I had a pretty hard time getting `FluentAsserts` to see that the `propertyChanged` was invoked.  It does not seem to happen if I use a `Task.Delay` in an `async Task` method.  But it does if I just sleep the thread.

The `SimpleNotify` class:

```
namespace FluentAssertPropertyThreads
{
    class SimpleNotify : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void onChange(string name)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        private int count = 0;
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return this.count;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.count != value)
                {
                    this.count = value;
                    this.onChange(nameof(this.Count));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here are my unit tests:

```
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FluentAssertPropertyThreads
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private SimpleNotify simpleNotify;
        private int notifyCount;
        private void bumpCount()
        {
            this.simpleNotify.Count++;
        }

        private void SimpleNotify_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SimpleNotify simpleNotify = sender as SimpleNotify;
            if (simpleNotify == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sender), "sender should be " + nameof(SimpleNotify));
            }

            if (e.PropertyName.Equals(nameof(SimpleNotify.Count), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                this.notifyCount++;
            }
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void TestSetup()
        {
            this.notifyCount = 0;
            this.simpleNotify = new SimpleNotify();
            this.simpleNotify.PropertyChanged += SimpleNotify_PropertyChanged;
            this.simpleNotify.MonitorEvents();

            Thread thread = new Thread(this.bumpCount)
            {
                IsBackground = true,
                Name = @"My Background Thread",
                Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
            };
            thread.Start();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task TestMethod1()
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            this.notifyCount.Should().Be(1);        //this passes, so I know that my notification has be executed.
            this.simpleNotify.ShouldRaisePropertyChangeFor(x => x.Count);       //but this fails, saying that I need to be monitoring the events (which I am above)
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            this.notifyCount.Should().Be(1);        //this passes, so I know that my notification has be executed.
            this.simpleNotify.ShouldRaisePropertyChangeFor(x => x.Count);       //this passes as I expected
        }
    }
}
```

The exact error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Object  is not being monitored for events or has already been garbage collected. Use the MonitorEvents() extension method to start monitoring events.

I don't see how `MonitorEvents` would care if I use await or `Thread.Sleep`.  What am I missing? I get that `await` leaves the method and comes back in, whereas `Thread.Sleep` does not.

So when it leaves the `TestMethod1` during the await, it is hitting a dispose on an object that `FluentAsserts` is using to track the properties? Could it? Should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the things is like you said: `await` pauses the execution of current method and create a state machine to get back to the method after the `Delay` is done. But the caller (a UnitTest engine) doesn't expect your tests to be asynchronous and simply ends the execution, which leads to the disposal of the objects.

Stephen Cleary wrote a brilliant [MSDN article about Unit testing and `async/await` keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx), you probably should move your code out to the method returning the `Task` and wait for all of it in test, something like this:

```
async Task Testing()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    this.notifyCount.Should().Be(1);
    this.simpleNotify.ShouldRaisePropertyChangeFor(x => x.Count);
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    await Testing();
}
```

but this still may fail as the logic after `await` may execute after the disposable being disposed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like version 5.0.0 will include support for Async tests with monitoring.

This [Issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/477) was raised and the [work completed](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/pull/625) just waiting on the documentation to be [updated](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/592) and version 5.0.0 to be released.

But for the time being there is a prerelease with the code changes [5.0.0-beta2](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/releases/tag/5.0.0-beta.2) can get it from the prerelease versions on NuGet

From the change log:

> {Breaking} Replaced the old thread-unsafe MonitorEvents API with a new
>   Monitor extension method that will return a thread-safe monitoring
>   scope that exposes methods like Should().Raise() and metadata such as
>   OccurredEvents and MonitoredEvents

So the code with the updated NuGet will look like this:

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestSetup()
{
    this.notifyCount = 0;
    this.simpleNotify = new SimpleNotify();
    this.simpleNotify.PropertyChanged += SimpleNotify_PropertyChanged;

    Thread thread = new Thread(this.bumpCount)
    {
        IsBackground = true,
        Name = @"My Background Thread",
        Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal
    };
    thread.Start();
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    using (var MonitoredSimpleNotify = this.simpleNotify.Monitor())
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        this.notifyCount.Should().Be(1);
        MonitoredSimpleNotify.Should().RaisePropertyChangeFor(x => x.Count); // New API for Monitoring
    }
}
```